# Docker web server

Tags: php, web, docker, webserver

I am looking for a method to access php tool via webpage of my apache (or other) server that would usually be accessed on http://myserver/app/index.php, 
IF I have a docker container with web server installation that is occupying http://myserver.

I considered 'entering' container and installing php tool inside, but wanna check if better solution exists.

Thanks.

Comment: It  would be helpful to mention what you have tried up to now. otherwise this would be a broad question.

Answer (score 0):

- Check for official images from DockerHub. Php repos can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)
- Use the official image as base image, extend it by writing your own [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), to add server dependencies, code to be run etc
- Create a image from the Dockerfile and use it.

I suggest this way against entering a container, installing your requirements and committing the container as it is not a scalable option in long run.